# Calculating a mass resistance to acceleration

Tags: c++, physics

Im not sure if this is the right place for this question, but I need to calculate the velocity of a large amplitude pendulum, with my current code it results in a sinusoidal graph.

The problem is that the period of the pendulum becomes smaller if I increase the mass, which shouldn't happen in a real pendulum because the period is independent of mass; The acceleration increases with mass but resistance to acceleration does too, and I don't know how to code this.

I have tried looking into angular momentum but my knowledge of physics is very limited. I have this:

```
long double timeFrame = 0.01;
    if(getNewAngle==true)
{
    //Convert to radians.
    myAngle = Angle*M_PI/180;
    getNewAngle = false;
    //Velocity starts at 0.
    myVelocity = 0;
}
//Setup starting variables.
long double dLength = std::stod(Length,0);
long double dGravity = std::stod(Gravity,0);
long double dMass = std::stod(Mass,0);
long double dPeriod = std::stod(Period,0);

//Large amplitude pendulum acceleration formula
long double dAcceleration = -dMass*dGravity/dLength*sin(myAngle);
//Angular displacement formula;
long double dDisplacement = myVelocity*timeFrame+0.5*dAcceleration*pow(timeFrame,2);
myVelocity = dDisplacement/timeFrame;
myAngle = myAngle + dDisplacement;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about physics than programming.  physics.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this question.

Comment: I agree with @JimLewis, you need to know what equation you're implementing before you start. If you can't infer what value is coming in as wrong by the output, then you should break the problem into sub sine-waves that you can predict the results to and then combine them.

Comment: [These might be useful](http://chrishecker.com/Rigid_body_dynamics)

Comment: A better place for this question is https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Apart from the physics it's also a debuging help question.  And there we require a statement of what was intended and what went wrong - which is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
//Large amplitude pendulum acceleration formula
long double dAcceleration = -dMass*dGravity/dLength*sin(myAngle);
```

is incorrect. It should be this:

```
//Large amplitude pendulum acceleration formula
long double dAcceleration = -dGravity/dLength*sin(myAngle);
```

That's right, mass doesn't enter into it (unless you start to consider air resistance).